# How to update magento2 from 2.0.0 to 2.0.2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, json

The docs here say that you should use the system upgrade utility:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html
and do it from the admin.

I thought that you would be able to update it by changing the composer.json file to     `"version": "2.0.2",` and then just run `composer update`.

Would this be another way to update or system upgrade utility is the only way of doing it?

Comment: Not sure if you come across this guide https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-2-x-to-latest-version/

Comment: https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-upgrade may help someone

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The recommended way in the documentation is via admin:

```
System > Web Setup Wizard > System Upgrade.
```

(http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html)

You must have crons enabled or it will not work. Make sure in configuration you have your keys inserted. If it freezes with no output in the logs you can check the php logs to see if it timed out and then increase the memory_limit in .htaccess to 2G.

The **second way** is with composer:

In `composer.json` change this line

```
"magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.0",
```

Also you should change the line 5 as well `"version": "2.0.0",` to keep it in sync.

to whatever version you want, and then run:

```
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Probably doesn't matter but are you supposed to change the version in line 5 as well? "version": "2.0.0"

Comment: Does upgrading from older to newer version affects Data Loss? We have to take backup before Upgrading?

Answer (score 55):

Updating/Upgrading to Magento 2.0.2 (via `composer`)

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.2 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

> **Upgrading to Magento 2.3.x**

The above commands work fine while upgrading Magento to 2.2.x.

To upgrade to Magento 2.3.x, you need to follow some more steps.

Here's the step-by-step guide to upgrade Magento to 2.3.x:

**Enable maintenance mode**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

**Specify Magento packages**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.0 --no-update
```

**Specify additional packages**

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update
```

**Remove unused packages**

```
composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
```

**Update autoload**

Open `composer.json` and edit the `"autoload": "psr-4"` section to include `"Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    ...
}
```

**Apply updates**

```
composer update
```

**Clean the Magento cache**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Manually clear caches and generated content**

Clear the `var` and `generated` subdirectories:

```
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/generated/code/*
```

or Single Line

```
rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* var/report/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_cache/merged/*
```

If you use a cache storage other than the filesystem, such as Redis or Memcached, you must manually clear the cache there too.

**Update the database schema and data**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Disable maintenance mode**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

**Finally, check your Magento version**

```
php bin/magento --version
```

*Read more: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html*

Comment: Also need to change  "version": "2.0.2"

Comment: I successfully upgrade my Magento from Magento 2.1.0 to 2.1.6 but there is a problem in CSS. I can't fetch my CSS.   All comes in Straight line.                           Errror:-GET http://127.0.0.1/fuelpump/pub/static/frontend/fuelpump-new/theme/en_US/css/styles-m.css 
(index):20 GET http://127.0.0.1/fuelpump/pub/static/frontend/fuelpump-new/theme/en_US/css/styles-l.css   @Mukesh Chapagain

Comment: Will it upgrade sample data as well ?

Comment: if you are looking proper solution visit this page  https://www.codedecorator.com/magento-2-upgrade-service.html

Answer (score 14):

Just upgraded successfully to Magento 2.2.6 through composer:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update
```

Change the version accordingly e.g. 2.2.6

```
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/page_cache
```

*// The issue following commands one by one

```
chown -R user:group .
chmod u+x bin/magento
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
ph bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If getting permissions error, issue:

```
chown -R user:group .
```

command again where user and group correspond to your server user and user group.

Comment: awesome just searched for that because setup wizard failed to upgrade with no reason. this works for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can upgrade Magento 2 version via admin panel or from terminal area Upgrade
:

**Admin Area Upgrade**

Navigate to System > Web Setup Wizard > System Upgrade

**Terminal Area Upgrade**

Before you start please apply the MDVA-532 patch, open your terminal and enter this:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
composer update
```

Next enter the following line to update the database schema and data.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Reference source which I followed to upgrade magento 2 version on my site (with screenshot and step by step) http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-version-via-backend-or-terminal

Answer (score 1):

Changing version and running `composer update` is for those who have access to command line, and have experience in using command lines(developers and SIs). The upgrade via admin is mainly for those who may have limited technical abilities or no access to command line via their hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

With version 2.0.2, fix is to upgrade the Magento installer first and then to force the upgrade of the core.

```
composer require magento/magento-composer-installer

composer require magento/product-community-edition '2.0.*' --no-update

composer update
```

And when you're done upgrading all PHP packages, make sure to run all Magento update scripts so that the database is up-to-date as well:

```
./bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the root directory of your store and run these commands:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.2 --no-update
```

**You can change the version**

```
composer update

rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case composer and Web Wizard ways fail there is a third approach:

1. Download the latest Magento 2 of [the official website](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download).
2. Unzip it into your main Magento directory.
3. Run: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`.

Take from this [source](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-upgrade-service).

Answer (score 0):

One can upgrade magento 2 using the two basic methods, one is from admin panel and other is using composer

Answer (score 0):

> Would this be another way to update or system upgrade utility is the only way of doing it?

Definitely this isn't the only way.

1. There first option is that you need to **create a new website** on Magento version 2.0.2, then migrate all your data from your current website on the Magento old version to the new one.
2. You can choose a **Composer update**, you have to change the line:
   `"magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.0"` in **composer.json**

Beside, you need to keep it in sync by changing the line 5 to `"version": "2.0.0"`.

And finally, you must run this command:

```
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```