# Magento2 System Upgrade Error

Tags: magento2, upgrade

Just went to upgrade my Magento2 installation by going to `System > Web Setup Wizard` and all I got was this:

[image]

I know I can upgrade via the command line from [this excellent answer here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108672/26241), but I was wondering if this error I am experiencing is normal? Or does it indicate something else has gone horribly wrong somewhere?

Comment: Anything in your logs ?

Comment: Do you know what am I looking for exactly? I did a search of `system.log` and `debug.log` (the only log files which have been modified today) for `upgrade` and couldn't find anything - nothing else stood out as being connected to this issue, but both files are many Mb's big and contain thousands of lines...

Comment: Anything in your browser console? Usually this happens when system permissions have been changed. Please change it according to recommended values, and it should be working file.  See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html