# How do you upgrade from Magento 2.0.x to 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, upgrade

Does anyone here know how to upgrade from Magento 2.0.x to Magento 2.1 without losing the changes I made to Magento 2.0.x?

when i type in php composer.phar update, the command prompt says that the requested package magento/product-community-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update magento2 from 2.0.0 to 2.0.2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99813/how-to-update-magento2-from-2-0-0-to-2-0-2)

Comment: I followed the instructions there. However, when i type in php composer.phar update, the command prompt says that the requested package magento/product-community-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name

Comment: @NikJiveShizzle please add above comment to your question, so that it won't be closed as duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: Just for more clearity, could you post the actual command you are entering?

Answer (score 2):

If you made changes to the magento core then when you upgrade the changes will be overridden.

The way I would go about it is to make a backup of the live site. I would go into the file system and make a complete copy of the root install - leaving the live site completely in tack. Then upgrade the backup and see what broke, using the live site as an example. It would then be possible to make the changes to the backup until your happy with the overall setup. Then just change the name of the folders from "domain-backup" to "domain"

Just my .02 cents - hope it helps.