# Migrating data to a new and clean installation in version 2.x

Tags: database, migration, marketplace, user

I would like to migrate all my Magento data to a new installation on version 2.3. We are currently on version 2.2.0 which has the Webkul Marketplace Extension.

Basically, all I want to extract from the current installation is
1. Vendor data from the Marketplace Extension
2. Customer data + orders
3. Users and roles
4. Products and all related data

Is there a way I can extract this from my database or from magento itself?

Comment: can you please visit: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99813/how-to-update-magento2-from-2-0-0-to-2-0-2#answer-108672

Comment: why not update magento2?