# migrate magento 2 github to download magento 2 website

Tags: magento2, magento-community, github

Previous freelance developer installed magento2 using GitHub.
and this website is in live now.
Now we come to know we need to install magento2 from the magento website.
how to migrate?

Present: 2.2.7 community github repo.
What we want: 2.3.1 from the magento2 website.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below link,

This will help you to upgrade your magento.

[How to update magento2 from 2.0.0 to 2.0.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99813/how-to-update-magento2-from-2-0-0-to-2-0-2)

Hope above link may help you.