# How can I update my Magento version 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 in a simple way?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, magento2.3.3

I have no idea how to about magento 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 
can anyone tell how to update it in a simple manner.
can it be possible with composer or anything else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update magento2 from 2.0.0 to 2.0.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99813/how-to-update-magento2-from-2-0-0-to-2-0-2)

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade Magento version 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 using cli and follow below steps:

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable 
>  composer require
>   magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 --no-update
>  composer
>   update
>  rm -rf var/* pub/static/* generated/*
>  php bin/magento
>   setup:upgrade
>  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>  php bin/magento
>   indexer:reindex
>  php bin/magento cache:clean
>  php bin/magento
>   maintenance:disable
>  check your Magento version with the Below
>   command
>  php bin/magento --version

Comment: thanks it worked i had tried some other ways but this works exactly what i wanted